# I have a projectile going through the air, point in front, flat plate in the rear. How do I calculate the aerodymanic forces on the rear plate?

Tags: aerodynamics

The project that the projectile is being developed for has nothing to do with aerodynamics, but the problem is that the rear plate is being sucked off - obviously not attached sufficiently. How can I predict what the aerodynamic forces on the rear of the projectile will be? The projectile is basically a nose cone, a tube, and a flat rear end (no boat tail) that just fits into the tube.

Comment: I would say that your question has everything to do with aerodynamics, but nothing to do with aviation.  VTC.

Comment: Agree, good question, but would belong to physics stack exchange.

Comment: Ok, I'll try there. There were some other aerodynamics questions here, so I thought I'd try.

Answer (score 1):

Use this diagram of base pressure coefficient over Mach. The high Mach values are from X-15 tests, the rest from a multitude of flight and wind tunnel tests. For your bullet the 3D line would be relevant; if you were looking at the blunt trailing edge of a wing, use the 2D line.

[image: base pressure coefficient over Mach]